# php foreach syntax without {}

Tags: php, foreach

I was reading through a php to python article which was talking about pythons equivalent of `foreach()` they gave the php code example as

```
foreach ( $items as $item )
    echo $item;
```

Is this a valid syntax without the `{}` ive always seen it written as

```
foreach ( $items as $item ){
    echo $item;
}
```

I ran the first example through coderunner locally to see if it would through an error and it didnt, is this a valid syntax to use or will i run into problems using it ?

Comment: Readability problems only.

Comment: do not use it, do not use it even with `if's` this syntax does nothing to help the code readers

Comment: I think if the content of the foreach is on one line only, it's valid.Same happens with `if`

Comment: @Mave Thanks, nice duplicate find!

Comment: First result in Google for "foreach without brackets"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Treat `foreach` and `{ ... }` as 2 different and independent language constructs.

The original `foreach` syntax is

```
foreach (...)
    statement
```

`echo $item;` is a valid statement.

`{ // any code here }` is a single valid statement as well.

Answer (score 5):

Yes this is valid. I have often seen this written as

```
<?php 
foreach($array as $element): 
  //do something 
endforeach; 
?>
```

See - http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: this is different and used in templating more. It supports 2 or more lines between opening and ending

Answer (score 2):

It is valid assuming that there is one statement "inside" the `foreach` loop. This actually generalizes beyond `foreach`, it works for `for`, `while`, `if`, etc. Additionally, it is not specific to PHP, many languages support this single-statement short hand.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a valid example. It will only work if there is one statement to be executed, or the statement cascades into another conditional/statement.

So while the following example is not valid, (that is only the first echo will be executed within the loop).

```
foreach( ... )
    echo ...
    echo ...
```

This example still is

```
foreach( ... )
    if( ... )
        echo ...
```

Comment: "one line in the statement" --- ? `echo 'foo \n bar';` (where `\n` is a real new line). Or `echo 1; echo 2;` --- still one line. It has **nothing** to do with number of lines there. It must be rewritten to remove any mentions of lines.

Comment: Your quite right, fixed.